# How to remove complicated shapes in ArcGIS - generalization

Tags: arcmap, polygon, geometry, generalization

What can be the way of simplifying polygons in ArcMap? I have a shapefile with buildings and I have to make them as simple as it's possible. I used already some tools, like: `dissolve`, `union`, `generalize`, `integrate` and even `buffer`. I still have something like this to remove:
[image: small angle]

Small angle between buildings makes problems with mesh generation I want to do afterwards. Any ideas how to remove it massively for all objects? I know I can increase buffer distance, but maybe there is something which will not change geometry that much.

EDIT:
After using `Simplify Polygon` or `Simplify Bulilding` some areas are simplified (left side of picture) but not those I would be interested in:
[image]

And as an answer for the duplicate - my question is different, I don't want to delete overlapped lines, just remove holes which have very small angles.

Comment: Generalize with pointremove https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//007000000011000000 be sure to keep a backup. Simplify building also could help with orthogonality https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Simplify_Building/00700000000z000000/ again *keep a backup*.. bad things can happen and not be noticed for a while, if you don't have a backup it's hard to repair sections that aren't suitable.

Comment: The "flag" errors appear to be the inverse problem (extending out rather than protruding in), but the solution is similar -- Calculate "bend", and where extreme, drop the outlier vertex in favor of the nearest point along the distorted segment.

Comment: integrate should work in your case, but of course it could affect your other boundaries. Always work on a copy with integrate.